# Iterate all activities in one android app recursively

Tags: android, android-activity

If we look at one activity as a graph node, transition/calling from one activity to another as a graph edge, one android app can be conceptually converted into a graph. I am trying to see if there is any way to create such a graph starting from the first page/activity of an app.

Let us say we can use android UI test automator to help if needed.

Comment: "one android app can be conceptually converted into a graph" -- not necessarily. There can be an arbitrary number of instances of an activity, limited only by available memory.

Comment: thanks for the hint. for proof-concept purpose let us say there is only one instance per activity.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to see if there is any way to create such a graph starting from the first page/activity of an app.

It would be exceptionally difficult.

I am assuming that you are trying to hack... er, I mean, "analyze"... somebody else's app. In that case:

1. You have no idea how many activities there are, unless you are reverse-engineering the APK. And even then, you have no idea how those activities will be used (e.g., legacy app that is putting activities in tabs and not using them as an ordinary activity).
2. You have no way to know what triggers the activities to appear. For example, a certain activity might only appear via an "Easter egg"-style bizarre set of inputs. Some might be triggered by things outside the app itself, like a `Notification` or a third-party invocation of `ACTION_VIEW` for some MIME type the app supports. And some of the triggers may be dependent upon other inputs (e.g., a disabled action bar item that becomes enabled only if you have set up an account elsewhere in the app).

With full source code, you could do static analysis to find all `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` calls, and for simple variations you might be able to divine which activity starts which. Even that could get tricky in some cases, for complex `Intent` construction.

Comment: awesome thanks a lot commonsware! yeah i know it won't be easy, and was not looking for 100% accuracy.

i might be starting from analyze "static" transition first, meaning the transition from activity A to activity B not conditional and always there from the level of code. for example, there is always an transition to "about us" activity, or "contact us" activity, or "log in" activity, or "help" activity, etc.

which way is more likely leading to good results: